# Is there a way to use $regex with $all in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, rest, mern

I am developing an application in which an array of strings is received from the frontend. I have an array of keywords for each document in my mongoDB database. The strings received from the frontend might be substrings of the keywords. Now I need to query the database such that it returns all the documents which contain all those keyword substrings.
**Eg. Suppose**
keyword array for document 1: ["substation", "220/60", "kV"] 
keyword array for document 1: ["substation", "220", "kV", "delhi"]
keyword array for document 1: ["substation", "kV", "Bombay"]
The array received from the frontent: ["substa", "220"]

I need the database to return the first two documents as both elements of the received array are substrings of keywords in both documents. But the third document should not be returned as it does not contain "220". I haven't been able to develop a query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have queries for each of the keywords (which are essentially the same query), you can combine them with $and:

```
{'$and' => [<query for substa>, <query for 220>]}
```

Also you should consider [full text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Comment: This can work if i know how many input strings i'll get in the array but that is determined at runtime. Or else i'll somehow have to map through the array and include separate queries.